# Calling javascript function from MainPage.xaml.cs codebehind file in windows app

Tags: javascript, silverlight, code-behind, back-button, windows

I am developing a **Windows 8.1** application in **HTML5** and **Javascript** (**Silverlight**). I have got stucked in **hardware back button** functionality.

In MainPage.xaml.cs Codebehind file i want to call a javascript function from following method:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
// Here i want to call a javascript function
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling A Javascript function from Silverlight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534208/calling-a-javascript-function-from-silverlight)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
  Browser.InvokeScript("functionName");
}
```

And parameter can also be passed from here like this:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
      Browser.InvokeScript("functionName","param1");
    }
```